# Count the difference of time in a table using postgre sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

- I have a table named Job with created_date and start_date columns.
- I need to count the difference in start_date and created_date and find the count
- count difference of 1 day 2 days 3 days and so on

Help me with it, I am new in sql queries

Comment: Nothing on Google when you searched "Find the difference between two datetimes in days MySQL"?

Comment: `select timestampdiff(day, created_date, start_date) diff, count(*) cnt from job group by diff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer in postgresql it is:

```
select date_part('day',start_time - created_on) as Difference , count(*)  from Job
```

thanks for the replies to all

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following in SQL

```
SELECT TRUNC(START_DATE) - TRUNC(CREATED_DATE) DAYS FROM JOB;
```